# Auto Mail using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In the following code the body of the message is not working. I want to add body of the mail and Signature before and after Excel sheet.

1. I have to add details like "Dear "
2. Body of the mail like " Please find the details....."
3. Signature at last of the mail.
4. Attachment is repeating morethan 1 time for 2 and so on.

Please suggest a solution

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'

Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets("Pivot").Cells


For i = 2 To 3

Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Customer Group"). _
    ClearAllFilters

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Customer Group"). _
    CurrentPage = Sheet3.Range("A" & i).Value



    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With r.Parent.MailEnvelope.Item



    .To = Sheet3.Range("b" & i).Value
    .cc = Sheet3.Range("c" & i).Value
    .bcc = ""
    .Subject = "Unapplied of " & Sheet3.Range("A" & i).Value
    .body = " Please find attached file"



    '.attachments.Add ""


    .send

    End With

    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Define "not working"?

Comment: *not working* is not a useful problem description unless you explain how it's *not working*. Do you get an error message? Does it put the wrong text in the body? Does it do something else? You know **exactly** how it's not working as you expect, and we can't read your mind. If you want us to help you, **be specific** about the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to send an array of cells in the body of the email, right.  Please see the example below.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "you@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

You will find several other Excel/Outlook options from the link below.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm